# How to get a variable asp-route-parameter in ASP.NET MVC with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was wondering if anybody knows how I could get the selected values from my form selection options into my asp-route-brand and asp-route-price.. seeing as how the values can differ depending on what the user selects (I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, it's for an assignment).

Here's my view:

```
<form name="formid">
    <a>Filter by brand</a>
    <select name="brandoption">
        @foreach (string brand in Model.Brands)
        {
            <option id="brand" value="@brand">@brand</option>               
        }
    </select>
</form>

<form>
    <a>Filter by price</a>
    <select name="priceoption">

        @for (int i = 25; i < 200; i += 25)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i €</option>
        }
    </select>
</form>

<a id="btn" asp-controller="Boards"
   asp-action="FilterBoards" asp-route-brand=""  asp-route-price ="" class="btn btn-primary " >
  FIlter.
</a>
```

Comment: Hi @davy, are you sure you use the asp.net instead of asp.net core? asp.net does not support tag helper.

Comment: i'm using asp.net core(5)

Comment: That's not the problem you need to solve. You need to submit a html form, that's what they are for. eg Wrap your `<select`s in a single form. Use `asp-action` / `asp-page-handler` to generate the form action. Use `asp-for` to generate select names and bind the currently selected values. Turn your link into a `<button type="submit"`.

Comment: eg, follow a sample like this; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-input-tag-helper

Answer (score 0):

`asp-route-brand` and `asp-route-price` will generate to query string to the url when the app run. So you cannot set the value for these tag helper according to the form selection.

The convenient way I think is that you can use form submit to achieve your requirement:

```
<form name="formid" asp-controller="Boards" 
               asp-action="FilterBoards">   @*add tag helper here*@
    <a>Filter by brand</a>
    <select name="brand">   @*change the name*@
        @foreach (string brand in Model.Brands)
        {
            <option id="brand" value="@brand">@brand</option>
        }
    </select>
    <a>Filter by price</a>
    <select name="price">   @*change the name*@

        @for (int i = 25; i < 200; i += 25)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i €</option>
        }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>
```

Backend code:

```
public void FilterBoards(string brand, string price)//the name attribute in frontend 
                                                   //matches the parameter name in backend
{
    //....
}
```